# Angular2 project developed in .Net and committed in SVN not working in other machine

Tags: .net, angular2-template

I have committed my project in svn with all files , the project is completely new, and after installing all the necessary files like typescript and nodejs, the project is not getting run there, all files are working properly it is getting build as well, but in browser it is not running it is giving error like platform-angular-dynamic not found zone.js, but have checked all files are present, I am not getting what is the issue. Please help any suggestion or advice will be helpful.

P.S I know I am not giving any code or anything but the issue is versoining or installation fault.

Comment: You need to post the full error message. Then people can *maybe* point out what is wrong with your project and then you can *maybe* find out *why* it's wrong on your other PC after SVN.

Comment: @nvoigt, hi one thing I have noticed that on hosting it to iis and changing the path from /node_modules/ to ../node_modules/ it is working